# Why would deploying my azure web role through visual studio take a long time?

Tags: deployment, azure

When I deploy a web role to azure using the management portal, the process takes about 20 minutes. But, when I deploy using visual studio, it can take hours, and it's stuck in "Initializing"/"Waiting for host".  Eventually, it does deploy and run normally.

Any thoughts on what's wrong?

Notes:

- I'm deploying through visual studio in order to be able to use Intellitrace and the web deploy.
- No errors appear at any time during the deployment

Answer (score 0):

Installing web deploy, RDP, any plugins, etc. will lengthen the deployment time.  I am pretty sure that Web Deploy in particular will cause the machine to reboot which adds a few mins.  This is probably what you notice most (VM's reboot and it takes awhile to get back).

Comment: But it shouldn't lengthen it so much, should it? I waited hours this morning on a deploy.

Comment: And other deployments go much faster (again, on the order of 20-30 minutes), even with RDP & web deploy enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that deploying from Visual Studio releases the host(s) and acquires a new one. This is evident by the fact that the IP addresses associated with the roles typically change when you deploy from Visual Studio.

But upgrading via the Portal re-images the existing host(s).

That presumably accounts for a significant proportion of the time difference, especially if there isn't a host available in the relevant upgrade or fault domain.

Comment: This is definitely true.  Visual Studio does a Delete and New Deployment.  However, it is unclear if Geoff is upgrading through the portal or doing a new deployment himself (using VIP swap perhaps).  Upgrading should be faster.

Comment: New deployment... Upgrades would be nice but they don't always work for this scenario.